# Switching cells with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I've just started messing around with UICollectionViews and layouts. I'm wondering how I can accomplish the following:

[image: Layout]

Tapping on cell located on the 2nd row, middle column would expand that cell into the frame you see as red. Doing this basically switches cells (I guess it can be done this way?) while the other ones reposition themselves with his newly added cell.

Any ideas?
PS: The best way to describe this is the way Twitter #music does the cell animation when tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have some [custom cells like a uiTableView](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/)

on

> cellForRowAtIndexPath == 4

have the cell look like you want to, set layout, height for this cell too!

just use like it was a normal uiTableView

Comment: Well the 4th isn't the one that looks different. All the cells are the same green cell until the user taps on a cell then the cell switches to the look you see on the attached screenshot.

Comment: ok got it, still you can change it this way im proposing, just have on your custom cell 2 kinds of layout, so when you tap a cell you want to change you call the new layout, and then reload data

Comment: I guess the best way to describe this is the way Twitter #music does the animation.

Comment: Hey MrShoot have got it working ?? i do wanted to make that kind of collectionview .... any help